# dynamic array with unknown size

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, malloc

I want to write a program in C where the user types in 2 numbers a and b.

0 < a < INT_MAX

a < b < INT_MAX

The program checks how many Prime numbers are in between a and b and saves all of them in a dynamic array.

For the `malloc` function I need the size of the array, which means I have to first check all numbers if they are prim numbers just to get the size of the array,
then use `malloc()`,
and then check all numbers again to fill the array.
Is there any possibility to make this run faster and not doing the same thing twice?

```
for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
{
  if (check_if_prime(i) == 0)
    size++;
}
primze_numbers = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
int j = 0;
for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
{
  if(check_if_prime(i) == 0)
  {
    prime_numbers[j] = i;
    j++;
  }
}
```

Comment: do `malloc` and then `realloc ` to increase the array size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the size is unknown in the beginning, allocating the space for the size of one more element is inefficient.

One possible solution is: reallocate the space(Use `realloc`) twice the size of the previous size whenever the size is not enough.

```
Real size - Space size
    0            0
    1            1
    2            2
    3            4
    4            4
    5            8
    6            8
    7            8
    8            8
    9            16
    10           16
    ...          ...
```

This way, the times of reallocation is not much, and you don't waste much space.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use c++ - you can use std::vector which solves your problem.

Comment: And if you are able to use Python, or Java, or ... yes.

Comment: It is not the same. C is subset of C++, so you can freely compile your C code with C++ compiler and as a bonus get c++ standard library. And yes, I know about problems of compiling C code with C++.